# Delete drag and drop rectangle

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I can draw a drag and drop rectangle, but after drag and drop it, the previous copy of rectangle still in its place. How I can delete it?

```
namespace dragAndDropRect
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, rect);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Refresh();
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, e.X, e.Y, 30, 30);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First dispose the old rectangle and then create a new one

```
namespace dragAndDropRect
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, rect);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Refresh();
            g.Invalidate();
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, e.X, e.Y, 30, 30);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: g.invalidate();  is not valid